# Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm running the following script -

```
declare @eventname VARCHAR(64)
declare @eventid INT

set @eventname = 'event123'
set @eventid = (select tm.trgmst_id from trgmst tm where tm.trgmst_name = @eventname)

declare @trgjobmax INT
set @trgjobmax = (select max(trgjob_id) from trgjob)

declare @jobid TABLE (jobmst_id INT, trgjob_order INT)

insert into @jobid (jobmst_id, trgjob_order)
   select 
       jm.jobmst_id, max(tj.trgjob_order) 
   from 
       jobmst jm
   left outer join 
       trgjob tj on tj.jobmst_id = jm.jobmst_id
   inner join 
       workgrp wg on wg.workgrp_id = jm.jobmst_owner
   where 
       wg.workgrp_name in ('group1', 'group2', 'group3')
       and jm.jobmst_type = 2 
       and jm.jobmst_dirty <> 'X' 
       and jm.jobmst_id NOT IN (select tj.jobmst_id 
                                from trgjob tj
                                where tj.trgmst_id = @eventid)
   group by 
       jm.jobmst_id
   order by 
       jm.jobmst_id desc
```

The problem is I get this message -

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

The reason is that it is not always guaranteed to have a trgjob_order value so it displays as NULL.  I then have to run the following update script in the same transaction and it seems to work fine.

```
update @jobid
set trgjob_order = 0
where trgjob_order IS NULL
```

Is there a way to write this more elegantly?  The data I'm given looks correct so I'm taking the warning as just that... It's a warning but can be ignored because I'm doing an update POST to replace the NULL with 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ISNULL`

```
select jm.jobmst_id, ISNULL(max(tj.trgjob_order), 0) from jobmst jm
```

Your complete script

```
declare @eventname VARCHAR(64)
declare @eventid INT
set @eventname = 'event123'
set @eventid = (select tm.trgmst_id from trgmst tm where tm.trgmst_name = @eventname)
declare @trgjobmax INT
set @trgjobmax = (select max(trgjob_id) from trgjob)
declare @jobid TABLE (jobmst_id INT, trgjob_order INT)
insert into @jobid (jobmst_id, trgjob_order)
select jm.jobmst_id, ISNULL(max(tj.trgjob_order), 0) from jobmst jm
left outer join trgjob tj on tj.jobmst_id = jm.jobmst_id
inner join workgrp wg on wg.workgrp_id = jm.jobmst_owner
where wg.workgrp_name in  ('group1', 'group2', 'group3')
      and jm.jobmst_type = 2 and jm.jobmst_dirty <> 'X' and jm.jobmst_id
NOT IN (
select tj.jobmst_id from trgjob tj
where tj.trgmst_id = @eventid
)
group by jm.jobmst_id
order by jm.jobmst_id desc
```

Comment: That works!  not sure why I didn't catch that earlier.  FYI it still gives the warning which I'm not sure why...

Comment: Probably you are getting `NULL` in somewhere else. So try to find where you are getting `NULL` value and use `ISNULL` function return `0` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is MAX(ISNULL(Column,0)) not ISNULL(MAX(Column),0), this will remove the null before it is aggregated.

It works fine in this case, with MAX, but careful doing this with COUNT as it would produce different results (given a null is not counted and a ISNULL'ed value is)